# Replacing template's name path in template file

Tags: socialengine

I have purchased a template and I have uploaded and installed it successfully. After that I have navigated to the theme editor and used the Clone option to replace the template's name with my website's name. Everything replaced successfully except the logo path. It is shown like the following in the view source

```
img src='application/themes/template's name/images/logo.gif'
```

I want the above coding to be like

```
img src='application/themes/mywebsite's name/images/logo.gif'
```

Comment: Have you tried editing the theme/template file directly?

Comment: Yes I have edited manifest.php, theme.css and constant.css , but I couldn't find anything to replace.

Comment: To change website logo, we have different option: [See](http://www.socialengine.net/support/documentation/article?q=121&question=Add-a-Custom-Logo)